Expo different build variants
I followed the expo guide on creating two different app variants - DEV and non-dev. The original one that was built in the ios folder was the DEV variant as that .env file (.env.development) was loaded and it has the com.myapp.dev identifier in the Info.plist:
<array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>myapp-dev</string>
        <string>com.myapp.dev</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
 </array>

Now when i created my variant in xcode and followed the steps from the link above, i removed the .dev suffix from the identifier in xcode but still when i run my preview eas build which should use the non .dev identifier:
eas.json

"preview": {
      "channel": "production",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "ENVFILE": ".env.production"
      }
    },

My .env.production has the BUNDLE_ID=com.myapp and .env.development has the BUNDLE_ID=com.myapp.dev.
I still get Bundle identifier registered: com.myapp.dev in my eas cli output.. what did I miss here?
Did i maybe misunderstand the concept of having 2 variants - should have have different identifiers or not? my understanding is that yes they should be different..
